Twitter field on user profiles doesn't recognize new domain for service
While editing the profile and saving the Twitter link, we encountered an issue. The domain for Twitter has changed, and the current domain is now https://x.com/. However, the system still expects the old domain, which results in an error message.

I wasn't sure which repository was the right one to create the issue, so I picked one based on my understanding and created the issue. I kindly request the author to give me the opportunity to resolve this issue.

I'd rather just remove the field, per existing consensus. That's a destructive operation, so I'm hesitant until a better solution has been reached, but there's certainly no reason to add the new domain.

@wizzwizz4 it’s probably a much easier change to add the new domain. Much as I despise the site, it’s probably a quick change worth making.

@Jeremy When the field was added, Twitter was the kind of service that Stack Exchange was willing to promote. (It was essentially a big collaborative set of RSS feeds, and the home of several new and interesting knowledge-sharing communities.) Nowadays, Twitter opposes what Stack Exchange stands for (providing access to / preservation of accurate, useful knowledge). There's no reason to support it, beyond the historical. Users can change the x.com to twitter.com if they really want to edit this field.

Related: Is it time to reconsider Social Media links in "Share" and User Profiles, etc?

@wizzwizz4 I’m not sure the point of your comment is. I would also see it removed, but as you said that probably needs to be part of a more complete alternative, so we can at least spend two minutes fixing the regex so the existing implementation isn’t defective.

@Jeremy The system works as expected, but the Twitter for which it was created no longer exists. Stack Exchange does not have an X field on user profile pages, and that's by design. There's nothing defective about the current implementation, in my view.

Have you tried changing the x in x.com to simply twitter? twitter.com automatically redirects to the new domain x.com, so it could work.
